# SQL Server sniffer/debug utility

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a C# .net application which connects to a SQL Server. The application generates queries dynamically and fetches the data from the database. I would like to see the query it has generated and want to see it on the SQL Server side. Is there any sniffer tool or logs where I can see the exact query that has hit? Later I can run the query from Management Studio and check for the data.

Comment: Why was this on hold. Perhaps the op was interested in learning the SQLServer Profile which is common in troubleshooting.

Comment: It's called [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Profiler and from there you can trace every hit in your SQL server.

Hope this will help you.